# The data I got dynamically didn't work in the tailwind library. How can I solve it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

**I added the initial data as a class. I coded the incoming data to cross out the label if it exists in the class, but it didn't work. It doesn't give an error either.**

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function ShopList({ item, index }) {
const [checkValue,setCheckValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="mb-[0.125rem] block min-h-[1.5rem] pl-[1.5rem]" data-index={index}>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e)=> setCheckValue(e.target.checked)} />
        <label 
        className={`inline-block pl-[0.15rem] hover:cursor-pointer ${checkValue} true:line-through `}>
          {item}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hi Enes and welcome to SO. What class are you trying to add? Currently you're adding `true` or `false` to your classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a typo with your `checkValue`.

```js
<label
   className={`inline-block pl-[0.15rem] hover:cursor-pointer ${checkValue ? 'line-through' : ''} `}
>
   {item}
</label>
```